# Timer to the Grafana field

Tags: database, timer, grafana, influxdb, metrics

I'm trying to figure out is it possible to get timer to the Grafana field which counts `time in dev` of different features. When the feature is ready the timer will stop.

Example:

```
Feature name   |  Time in dev
-------------------------------
Something new  |      10s <-- timer field
```

I have tried to google and find the solution but for now I haven't found one. I'm using influx database in my project. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do... What feature?

Comment: I have a panel where I have feature names and the time how long they have been in dev. I need a field where timer in `time in dev` field is going like this... 1s, 2s, 3s, 4s, 5s and so on.